# ob_start() combined with wp_query

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, front-end

I'm making my first plugin and I have a problem with displaying my shortcode.
It shows in the top all the time but I have read some about ob_start(); and trying to use it but the shortcode just returns nothing.

Im using the code below - it seems to have something to do with my posts. Anyone know why how to solve this problem?

My WP_Query:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
'category__in' => $categories,
'posts_per_page' => $whpost_stored_meta_shortcode['whpost_number_of_posts'][0]
  ));
```

The code i use to display it:

```
ob_start();

echo '<div class="whpost_content">';
    while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
      // Get the URL to the attached image.
      $attached_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'large' );
      echo '<div class="whpost_post" style="width: ' . $post_width .'; background-image: url(' . $attached_image[0] . ');">';
        the_title();
      echo '</div>';
    endwhile;
  echo '</div>';

  return ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: Post the complete shortcode please

Comment: This code looks fine. Maybe post the code that you use to register the shortcode and also the full shortcode handler.